# Display Editable Text Above CPT Archive Listings

Tags: custom-post-types, archives, template-hierarchy

I have two custom post types (Authors and Partners). I display their archive page's in the main navigation and use archive-authors.php and archive-partners.php to make a couple small tweaks to the display of posts in each.

Now, my client would like to display some text before the archive's post listing. So far I can think of the following ways to do that:

1. Save the text as the post type's description and display that.
2. Create a separate page and hard code a custom `WP_Query()` loop for just that page (by ID) above the archive.
3. Write a custom loop with `WP_Query()` to produce the CPT archive for each CPT and setup "Author Archive" and "Partner Archive" templates that can be used on static, editable pages.

However, all of these solutions seem suboptimal for one or more of the following reasons:

- They require technical knowledge to update (#1, #2)
- It's not abstracted (e.g. the solution has to be custom-coded for each archive) (#2, #3)
- Updating the text requires technical knowledge (#1)
- The solution essentially duplicates the template hierarchy (#3).

I'm looking for a solution that's WordPress friendly, abstracted, and easy-to-update for the client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the easiest (although not the only) of ways to achieve this is by creating a custom options panel in the WP dashboard that will allow your client to create and update information that can be used through out your template files with no technical knowledge being necessary.

You can either paste the following directly into your functions.php file or you can save it in a file i.e. config-menu.php (within your theme directory) and then include it into your functions.php file - the choice is yours however the code is;

```
// create config menu in dashboard
add_action('admin_menu', 'config_menu');

function config_menu() {

    //create a menu in the dashboard
    add_menu_page('Website Custom Settings',
                  'Configure Site', 
                  'administrator',
                  __FILE__,
                  'custom_settings_page',
                  ''.get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/images/your_icon.png', 4);

}

//register settings
add_action( 'admin_init', 'register_settings' );

function register_settings() {

    register_setting(   'my-settings-group', 'partners');
    register_setting(   'my-settings-group', 'authors');
}

function my_settings_page() {
?>

<div class="wrap">

    <form method="post" action="options.php">

    <?php settings_fields('my-settings-group'); ?>

    Enter your Partner description here <br/>
    <textarea  name="partners"><?php echo get_option('partners');?></textarea>

    <br />

    Enter your Author description here <br/>
    <textarea  name="authors"><?php echo get_option('authors');?></textarea>
    <input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php _e('Save Changes') ?>" />

    </form>

</div>

<?php } ?>
```

Then in your archive template files for each post type you can do the following;

```
<?php echo wpautop(get_option('partners');?>

and

<?php echo wpautop(get_option('authorss');?>
```

This will call the respective values (text entered) into the textarea fields you have created in the dashboard area for the client.

NOTE: The example code above is very rudementary and its stripped down to provide you a basic example. No CSS styling provided which I'll leave up to you. But this will get the job done.

Comment: I'm still thinking this over, but I like the direction it's headed. I'm still not thrilled that it's not completely abstracted (as defined in the OP), but this seems like a good solution that I'll probably try out.

Comment: I assume that I can replace `<textarea>` with wp_editor() and use the `get_option(...)` as the first argument?

Comment: Yes see [HERE](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor) on how to pass values to setup wp_editor(). That aside what do you mean by completely abstracted? At someone you are going to have to insert some `placeholder` into your template files that says **"hey, call this bit of text from such and such place"** there's not much way around that but you only have to do that once. After that you've given your client the ability to control the information displayed in those areas at will without ever having to touch a piece of code.

Comment: Thanks again for your help on this @userabuser. I'm working on implementation and stuck on the wp_editor portion of things. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51248/two-wp-editor-fields-on-theme-options-page-not-saving

Answer (score 2):

**Update January 19, 2023:** The plugin mentioned in this answer is long-abandoned, but I forked it, improved it, and released it years ago as [Post Type Archive Descriptions](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-type-archive-descriptions/). [It's also on Github.](https://github.com/mrwweb/post-type-archive-descriptions/)

---

There is now a plugin [CPT Descriptions](http://wordpress.org/plugins/cpt-descriptions/) that does this.

As of v0.1, the plugin is pretty buggy (editors can't save descriptions), but most of the stuff is taken care of on the [GitHub repository version of the plugin](https://github.com/vanpop/CPT-Descriptions/tree/master/cpt-descriptions) and you can find some other changes/improvements amongst the [one existing fork](https://github.com/mrwweb/CPT-Descriptions) and pull requests. Hopefully those will be integrated into the WordPress repo version of the plugin, but for now they're up and tested on GitHub.

To use the plugin, simply install it, fill out the "Description" fields for each post type you desire and then output the description on an archive page with:

```
the_post_type_description();
```

or get a specific post type's description with:

```
the_post_type_description('my_post_type');
```

or save it to a variable with:

```
$description = get_post_type_description();
```

Comment: I just tested the latest version from GitHub (version number 0.2) under WP 3.8 and it appears to work perfectly.

Comment: @Dakota The big problem is that the descriptions are only editable by Administrators.

Comment: @mewweb Yes I see, I just tested and can easily explain it: to keep things simple, the plugin uses the [WordPress Options system](http://codex.wordpress.org/Option_Reference), which is only modifiable by Administrator role users. The plugin could be rewritten to use a Custom Post Type to store the data, which would give easy role permissions and also allow other metadata about custom post types to be easily stored. I'd do it myself, but I'm just another user of the plugin and currently don't have any need for those advanced features.

Comment: @Dakota the problem is actually that the options aren't quite implemented correctly. There is a filter to allow non-admin usage of options. I've implemented in [in this branch](https://github.com/mrwweb/CPT-Descriptions/tree/total_overhaul) but that hasn't been integrated into plugin and I'm not sure when/if it will.

Comment: Doesn't that filter allow *all* options? Probably not what you want, security-wise.

Comment: [As you can see here](https://github.com/mrwweb/CPT-Descriptions/blob/total_overhaul/cpt-descriptions/cpt-descriptions.php#L226) the filter is specific to the options page. In this case `option_page_capability_cptd_descriptions`.

Comment: Ahh, so I see. I had a couple line bug fix integrated into the main repo recently, I just created a nice clean pull request and pinged the author on twitter and he merged it the next day. If you want to see your options fix integrated, you should try having a single neat pull request for it. The author doesn't seem to be entirely against integrating fixes, though perhaps he's hesitant to merge a branch with a lot of big changes. If you don't have any luck, I'd be willing to write a pull request with the same changes and try it.

Comment: Sorry for 'hijacking' the discussion, but I had the same problem and I tried to use CTP-Description plugin but it's not working on all my CPTs. On some I have the description menu option and on some I don't. Is the plugin looking for something specific on a CPT?

Comment: Here's the [relevant code](https://github.com/mrwweb/CPT-Descriptions/blob/master/cpt-descriptions/cpt-descriptions.php#L31). Has to be public and not "built-in." (A CPT should never be built-in.)

Please keep in mind that the current plugin has some severe limitations and I don't think the author is really keeping it up.

Comment: Thanks for the info! My CPTs were not public, so that's the reason I had problems. In the end I think I might replace this 'description' with a section in the Theme Options menu. I also want to let the user change some colors in these CPTs so I think this would be the best way.